# Formating a string to keep the wanted

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, strip

I have an issue with this code:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from re import search

lsite=[]

try:
    NetworkDevice = {
        "host" : "ip",
        "username" : "username",
        "password" : "mdp",
        "device_type" : "cisco_ios"
    }

    connect = ConnectHandler(**NetworkDevice)
    connect.enable()
    command = "sh cdp nei"
    result = connect.send_command(command).strip()


    with open(r".\blabla.txt","w") as filout:
                filout.write(result)

    with open(r"blabla.txt") as temp_f:
        datafile = temp_f.readlines()
    for line in datafile:
        if search("AP", line):
            output = (f"{line}")
            lsite.append(output.strip())
            print(lsite[-1])
            

            
except(IndexError):
    pass
```

And I have this output:

```
056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
Gig 0/12          158             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0
054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
Gig 0/11          132             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0
052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
Gig 0/10          174             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0
050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
Gig 0/9           155             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0
```

I would like this output (maybe have to split in 2 outputs):

```
056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN    

Gig 0/12    
Gig 0/11    
Gig 0/10    
Gig 0/9
```

I tried many ways with `split()` or `strip()` but I found nothing which works.

The `print(lsite[-1])` is because only printing `lsite` shows me every lines who append my list like:

```
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN']
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0']
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN']
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', 
'052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN']
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', 
'052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/10          142             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0']
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', 
'052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/10          142             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN']
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', 
'052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/10          142             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0', '050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/9           177             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0']  
['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN']
```

Comment: FYI you don't need regex for this `if search("AP", line)` you could just `if "AP" in line`, and `output = (f"{line}")` could just be `output = line`

Comment: It looks like there's a newline in each of your `line`s. If you do `line.split("\n")` on each of those and put the zeroth and 1th entry resulting from that split into two separate lists, you could then print the lists separately after your loop. I say `line.split` because your `output` variable isn't doing anything with line, it's identical to `line.`

Comment: can you just prnit results and add tat to your answer

Comment: it would be useful to show the raw content of `blabla.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hoper this is what you need.

```
list_of_lists = [['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/10          142             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/10          142             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/12          123             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/11          154             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/10          142             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0',
      '050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN', 'Gig 0/9           177             T B I  AIR-CAP16 Gig 0'],
     ['056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN']]

lans = set()
gigs = set()
for outer in list_of_lists:
    for inner in outer:
        if ".LAN" in inner:
            lans.add(inner)
        else:
            gigs.add(inner.split("  ")[0])

for lan in lans:
    print(lan)

for gig in gigs:
    print(gig)
```

Output:

```
050_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
056_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
052_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
054_AP_GRANDE_TERRE.AMCMZ.LAN
Gig 0/11
Gig 0/12
Gig 0/9
Gig 0/10
```